# Button lost WM_LBUTTONUP after a modal dialog window show up

Tags: windows, winapi

I have a win32 application, there is an button on the main window.

When i click the mouse left button, i receive the WM_LBUTTONDOWN message, when i release the mouse left button, i receive the WM_LBUTTONUP message, that is normal.

However, if in the processing of message WM_LBUTTONDOWN, (while i am holding the mouse left button), the program show a modal dialog window, the button will never receive the WM_LBUTTONUP.

This becomes an issue because in the WM_LBUTTONDOWN the program did something that needs to be clear up in the WM_LBUTTONUP.  Now because of the modal dialog, there is no chance to clear up anymore.

Is there a better way to handle this? I tried SetCapture, seems still can not receive the WM_LBUTTONUP.

Answer (score 4):

This is quite reasonable. When you show the modal dialog it starts its own modal message loop. And so it will receive the `WM_LBUTTONUP` message.

The fundamental problem that you have is that you are showing the modal dialog in response to `WM_LBUTTONDOWN`, when in fact you should show it in response to `WM_LBUTTONUP`. Try pressing buttons in other applications and note that the action occurs only when the button goes up. You should do likewise and follow the platform standards.

Comment: how about the modal dialog pop up at other place, say in a WM_TIMER process, while i am holding the mouse left button, i assume that will have the same affect, will loose WM_LBUTTONUP.   A real example, when press  the mouse left button, turn on power, when release the mouse left button, turn off the power, however, the main  window process something in the middle, and detect an error for what ever reason and pop up an message window, then we lost WM_LBUTTONUP.    I am still thinking there should be a way to detect this kind of situation and have a way to handle this.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't really understand any of this. I think I've explained why you see what you see, and I've explained how you are expected to deal with button clicks, namely waiting until the button goes up before invoking the action.

Comment: What i am trying to say is there is a need/customer requirement for a program to process/invoke the action in WM_LBUTTONDOWN

Comment: If you show a modal dialog in response to `WM_LBUTTONDOWN`, then the modal message loop will get the `WM_LBUTTONUP` message.

Comment: @liuhongbo if your customer has needs that specific then they're setting themselves up for failure. Windows works the way David explained, there's no changing it.

Comment: We have the same problem here. The WM_LBUTTONDOWN starts a selection state, but this got interrupted by a modal dialog which is indirectly popped up (i.e. due to end editing a field in tree control). I have no solution except that above suggestion to use the WM_LBUTTONUP is pretty useless.

Comment: @gast128 I'm sorry my answer is so useless. Good luck solving your problem.

Comment: @Heffeman. I am sorry if I sound too harsh. I just don't like it when people answer that you shouldn't do it that way, while it is just a legitimate way.

Comment: @gast128 Actions should be invoked on mouse button up, that's how the system is designed to work. Do it on mouse button down and all sorts of things break. Feel free to ignore my advice. Your inability to recognise that does not make my answer useless.

Comment: @Heffeman: you are incorrect. For example if you make a selection in a window, you want the area to be selected between a mouse down and a mouse up event. You end the selection state on the mouse up event. It is vital that the down, move, up sequence isn't interrupted which is exactly the case here. Only for the case of button presses you are correct that one shouldn't do the action on up event that wasn't the original thread.

Comment: @gast128 The question that was asked describes a modal dialog being shown. What mouse marquee selection mechanism ever involves a modal dialog being shown in between the mouse going down and the mouse coming back up? If you want to ask a new question here referring to your problem, feel free to do so. I'm not really interested in arguing with you. My mind is made up. Yours also appears to be made up. What's to be gained from our conversation?

Comment: @Heffeman: indeed this discussion is ended in a stalemate. I quote the original question 'However, if in the processing of message WM_LBUTTONDOWN, (while i am holding the mouse left button), the program show a modal dialog window, the button will never receive the WM_LBUTTONUP.'. Your answer fiddles with the problem domain and essentially says 'don't do that'. That does't help much if you cannot change the problem stated, for example if something else in your program pops up the dialog indirectly as reaction on the left mouse button.